# I want to change this line JAVA to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to put this line in `kotlin` but i dont how to type the line in `kotlin`

`arFragment = (MyArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment)`

Answer (score 2):

You can add this function to a separate file:

```
inline operator fun <reified T> FragmentManager.get(@IdRes fragmentId: Int): T {
        return findFragmentById(fragmentId) as T
}
```

and get the fragments like this:

```
val someFragment: MyFragmentClass = supportFragmentManager[R.id.my_fragment]
```

[There you can read about inline and reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html)

[There you can read about overloading operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed)

[About casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/inheritance.html#casting-and-type-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Casting is simple in koltin just use this

```
variable as <class to cast to>
```

for your question it will be like this

```
arFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment) as MyArFragment
```

you can even use safe casting

```
variable as? <class to cast to>
```

this will avoid throwing an exception if the cast fails